# Union of cycles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with minimal degree $\delta(G) \geq 2$. The set of vertices $V(G)$ can be written as a union of cycles.

Question: is there a universal constant $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that every graph $G$ with $\delta(G) \geq 2$ can be written as a union of a collection ${\cal C}$ of cycles (not necessarily induced subgraphs, just subgraphs) such that whenever $C_1\neq C_2\in {\cal C}$ we have $|C_1\cap C_2| \leq k$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counterexample: Consider a graph consisting of three paths $u a_1\cdots a_{k-1} v$, $u b_1\cdots b_{k-1} v$, and $u c_1\cdots c_{k-1} v$, and no other vertices or edges. Every cycle contains exactly two of those paths so any two cycles share $k+1$ vertices.